# Scrapy and xpath weirdness - automatic adding of tags, axis and steps?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm having trouble understanding some of the details of how to use xpaths with scrapy. E.g.:

**Extra html-body padding I didn't add**

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
t = '<a href="123">qwer</a>'
sel = Selector(text=t)

sel.extract()
# returns: <html><body><a href="123">qwer</a></body></html>
```

Where is the html-body tags padding coming from?

**Axis and steps??**

```
sel.xpath('html').extract()  # returns [], ok
sel.xpath('body').extract()  # returns '<body><a ...' ?????
sel.xpath('a').extract()     # returns [], ok?
```

Why can I select 'body' without using '/'? I had similar behaviour with a 'div' element in a project.

Also the following:

```
sel.xpath('//body').extract()  # returns '<body>...', ok
sel.xpath('//body').xpath('/body').extract()
# this returns [].
```

Why doesn't the xpath chain return the same as the first line? The selectors seem to be same in both cases? Shouldn't the second xpath call work on a new root?

Comment: To the close voter: I have three explicit questions in there. Perhaps if you could let me know why they are not clear to you, I could improve the wording

Comment: It's best to ignore the people who say the question is unclear. Chances are that it's perfectly clear to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrapy Selector uses `lxml.html` parser to parse the input text and when lxml receives non full html (html fragment) it always wraps it to be a full html document tree I believe (same way the web browsers work for example).

Xpath expression work whole lot similar to the basic file system path expressions such as `/home/john/Downloads/file.pdf` (absolute path) or `Downloads/file.pdf` (relative path and is same as `./Downloads/file.pdf`).

Simple XPath expression such as `body` are also the same as `./body`, which means starting from current node locate `<body>` element which should be a direct child of current node. Dot refers to the current node, single slash to a single level below it (and double dash means any level below).

By default you are located relative to the html tree root (`<html>` node). Root node has no direct child element `<html>` so `xpath('html')` gives you nothing. Root node does have a direct `<body>` child so `xpath('body')` yields it. Root node has no direct `<a>` child so `xpath('a')` yields none (however you could retrieve it via `xpath('.//a')`).

This chaining `xpath('//body').xpath('/body')` does not work the way you think it works. First of, starting the expression with `/` or `//` (both are absolute paths) instructs the evaluator to start looking relative to the root of the document with no regard as to where you currently are. So your expression goes as: find body element anywhere in the document and then find body element which must be located at the very top (except there's only one element at the top and that is `<html>`).

Comment: Thanks, a question about the last part: `sel.xpath('//body')` returns a selector with xpath='//body' and data=<body...; so if I get it right, the xpath function I call on a selector, does not work on the given selector but the entire response? PS: I just tried `sel.xpath('//body').xpath('/html').extract()` indeed returns the whole document. I find this quite weird.... is there a rational behind it?

Comment: OK, I guess your filesystem analogy is the answer to my confusion... thanks!